# Replace elements in 2D list with corresponding value in dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a 2D Python list. I also have a dictionary. I want to generate a numpy matrix of the same shape as the list where each element in the list is replaced with the corresponding value in the dictionary.

For instance, this is my Python List:

[[ John Mary]

[ Jim Jane]]

I would like this to create this for instance (a numpy matrix, not a 2D Python list):

[[85 53]

[76 45]]

Where the values are retrieved from a dictionary.

What's the **fastest** way to do this? I need this to be *extremely* fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function to the whole numpy array:

```
>>> pylist = [['John','Mary'],['Jim', 'Jane']]
>>> nparray = np.asarray(pylist)
>>> print nparray
[['John' 'Mary']
 ['Jim' 'Jane']]
>>> dt = {'John':86, 'Mary':53, 'Jim':76, 'Jane':45}
>>> func = np.vectorize(lambda x: dt[x])
>>> print func(nparray)
[[86 53]
 [76 45]]
```